# Selecting Stored Procedure Value in Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I found numerous threads close to this but non answer my question exactly so here goes.

I am writing a report that needs to use a variable I declared as one of the SELECT fields.

Here is the store procedure code:
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_Test

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Test`(facilityId INT, startDate DATE, endDate DATE)
BEGIN

DECLARE facilityName VARCHAR(256);

SELECT facility_name INTO facilityName FROM `reporting`.`facilities` WHERE `reporting`.`facilities`.facility_id = facilityId;

SELECT `reporting`.`error_stratification`.description AS Stratification, facilityName
...Rest of query that is not important

END
```

The only problem is that it puts the string "facilityName" in my query results not the value of it.

Is there a way to force it to output the value there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cleaned up your code a little - the following should provide a good starting point from which you can continue...

```
drop procedure if exists sp_test;

delimiter #

create procedure sp_test(
in p_facility_id int unsigned, -- p prefix = parameter
in p_start_date date,
in p_end_date date
)
begin

declare v_facility_name varchar(255) default null; -- v prefix = variable

select f.facility_name into v_facility_name from facilities f where
 f.facility_id = p_facility_id limit 1;

select f.*, upper(v_facility_name) as facility_name from facilities f;

end#

delimiter ;

call sp_test (1, curdate() - interval 1 month, curdate());
```

Comment: Using an aggregate function seemed to have fixed the problem. I am not sure if this is a bug in MySQL or what, but I sent it into the support team there asking for a clarification with no word yet. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into the basics of MySQL stored procedures.

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm this will help you out.

Comment: I don't see anything in there regarding what I am doing other than it showing a SELECT INTO statement.

I have also updated the original question showing the structure of my stored procedure to fix any confusion on it.

Answer (score 0):

- [DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html)

> You don't really define variables within the stored procedure. You define them within the BEGIN/END block.

Also might be helpful to you, depending on what you are trying to do:

- [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Sorry should have clarified it is inside the BEGIN/END block of the stored procedure.

Comment: I also attempted to use User-Defined variables as well, but in a stored procedure it treats the statement containing := as a string so I get (@facName:=facility_name) string from a SELECT statement.

Comment: I have also updated the question to show the whole structure of the stored proc to show the BEGIN/END block.